# Can't add block to 'content'

Tags: layout, blocks

I can't reference `content` to add block in content. I try adding block to `head` and it works. But not the content.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly turn on template hints under `system->configuration->developer->debug`.  If you don't see an option for template hints change the current configuration scope to a website of store in the drop down top left.  Now view the frontend and look at the template right at the top, this is your root block template.  It will normally be `1column.phtml`, `2columns-left.phtml`, `2columns-right.phtml` or `3columns.phtml`.  If it's not one of these then you are probably using a custom root template.

Open the template you see and check the following line exists somewhere:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

This is the line which outputs all of the blocks which you add as children to the `content` block.  The content block should be of type `core/text_list` and is normally declared in the `page.xml` layout file as follows:

```
...
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
    <label>Main Content Area</label>
</block>
...
```

When a block is of type `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List` it will automatically render out any child blocks added to it according to the positions assigned to each child block using `before` and `after` when declaring the block.  Without this block type you need add an explicit call to `$this->getChildHtml()` at the relevant point in your template to output the block content.  So find wherever the `content` block is defined in your theme's layout files and ensure it is of type `core/text_list`.

Once you have checked the root template for the `getChildHtml()` call, and ensured the `content` is in the layout and is of type `core/text_list`, you can then add content to that block with something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default> <!-- use your layout handle, default add to most pages -->
        <reference name="content"> <!-- this references the content block added in the template -->
            <block type="module/block" name="some block" template="module/template.phtml" after="-" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

With all this in place, assuming you have declared it correctly you will see your block render out on the frontend.